# «Применение жестокости» — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Услышала сегодня в телепрограмме "Место встречи":
*Нас осуждают за неоправданное **применение жестокости.***

Мне это словосочетание *показалось* диссонансным (вот только не могу понять — чем?).
Применение силы, применение оружия, применение хитрости — эти словосочетания на слуху.
А вот *применение жестокости* (применить жестокость) — грамотно ли так говорить?

Comment: Тоже коробит. Примерно, как **применение доброты* :) Впрочем, в разговорной речи такое сейчас сплошь и рядом. Вчера где-то попалось обсуждение фразы, кажется, Навального: *убедиться собственными глазами* (где, на мой взгляд, диссонанс не каждый и заметит). В вашем примере, конечно, у говорящего в голове было что-то вроде *применение силы* + *жёсткое* (вряд ли *жестокое*), а вслух получилось вот такое вот.

Comment: Правильно: _применение жестоких методов_ или _проявление жестокости_ - при отрицательной оценке со стороны. "Жёсткость" - современное дипломатичное наименование жестокости в контекстах её оправдания. Нейтральное выражение - "применение силы".

Comment: Нас осуждают за неоправданно-жесткое применение силы. Нас осуждают за применение неоправданно-жестких методов.

Answer (score 2):

Это **неправильно** (аналогично: "применить снисходительность"), поскольку жестокость - внутреннее свойство, которое можно *проявить*, но нельзя "применить" (*применить* можно *жестокие методы* обращения с кем-л. - в полицейском контексте).

Comment: Alex_ander, а как же быть с хитростью? Хитрость — это ведь тоже внутреннее свойство, а сочетаемость считается правильной: *применить хитрость*. (Словарь сочетаемости: https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.) _Я не хотел отпускать ее к Керну. И я решил **применить хитрость**_. [А. Р. Беляев. Голова профессора Доуэля (1925)]

Comment: "Применить хитрость" если и приемлемо, то как военный жаргонизм. "Применить смекалку" - из той же области; в этом есть и легкая ирония, и направленость на выполнение боевой задачи. Не думаю, что с жестокостью такое может пройти, поскольку открытое признание (в полицейском сообществе) жестокости "методом" разрушало бы репутацию соотв. ведомства.

Answer (score 1):

*Применение жестокости* — это профессиональный оборот в среде юристов, который стабильно используется как минимум с начала двухтысячных.

Самое раннее упоминание, что мог найти: из расшифровки [интервью BBC с Солженицыным](https://www.bbc.com/russian/features-38379654) 1976 года (отметки говорящих мои):

> *Новгородцев С.:* И ещё одно мне показалось очень интересным. Ленин много говорит о том, что страдания, война, потери неизбежны в ходе революции. Но в то же самое время он мало говорит о том рае, который стремится создать. Читая вашу книгу, я задавался вопросом: отказываются ли революционеры от этих жестоких мер после того, как уже нет необходимости в этих жестокостях?
>
> *Солженицын А.:* Я думаю, что есть заглатывающая инерция в том, чтобы **применять жестокость и насилие**. И даже если вначале кто-либо имел идеальные цели на более позднее время, то действительно в этой заглатывающей инерции он не может выскочить из неё. И, собственно говоря, "Архипелаг ГУЛаг" в первой части отвечает на этот вопрос: что же сделал Ленин, придя к власти. Да, когда все силы интеллекта и ума употреблены на захват
> власти, не остаётся сердечных сил подуматьоб обещанном рае. Да.

Полагаю, что является калькой с английского "use of brutality"/"using brutality". Хотя возможно, что и самостоятельное формирование.

Звучит диссонантно, поскольку весьма редкая и специфическая фраза.

Не соглашусь с [@Alex_ander](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/463471/197493). Если обратиться к словарю, то у слова *жестокость* определяется два значения. Из словаря Ефремовой<sup>1</sup>:

> жестокость
>
> 1. Отвлеч. сущ. по значению прил.: жестокий.
> 2. Жестокий поступок.

Из словаря Ожегова<sup>2</sup>:

> ЖЕСТОКОСТЬ -и, жен.
>
> 1. см. жестокий.
> 2. Жестокий поступок, обращение. *Допустить ж*. *Жестокости не прощаются*.

Говоря о "внутреннем свойстве", вы подразумеваете первое значение. Жестокое обращение является альтернативным значением слова *жестокость*. Соответственно, чисто технически, фраза *применить жестокость* вполне корректна.

---

1. Ефремова Т. Ф. Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный: В 2 т. — М.: Русский язык, 2000.
2. Ожегов С. И., Шведова Н. Ю. Толковый словарь русского языка — М.: Азъ, 1992.

Comment: Применить жестокий поступок. Применить жестокое обращение. -- не очень-то корректно, технически

Comment: Да у подхода и обхождения общий корень, но и только. Применить вежливое поведение чтобы получить конфетку. -- звучит нелепо, на мой взгляд.